# Scheduler instance recovery causing inconsistent behavior in Quartz cluster

Tags: synchronization, wildfly, quartz-scheduler, jbpm, kie

I have a Quartz cluster consisting of multiple nodes running in a high-availability setup. Recently, I encountered an issue where one of the scheduler instances was still active but was recovered by another instance in the cluster. This situation is causing inconsistent behavior and leading to conflicts in job execution.

The error message I received is:
"This scheduler instance (PRS1VM3621671144807726) is still active but was recovered by another instance in the cluster. This may cause inconsistent behavior."

To provide some context, here are the details of my setup:

Quartz version: 2.2
Cluster configuration: two kie-server deployed on two host HC3 et HC4 in same cluster wildfly domain mode

I have already reviewed the Quartz documentation and tried a few troubleshooting steps, such as adjusting the org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval and org.quartz.jobStore.maxMisfiresToHandleAtATime properties. However, the issue still persists.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Specifically, I would like to know:

What could be causing this scheduler instance recovery problem in my Quartz cluster?
Are there any additional configuration settings or steps I should consider to ensure consistent behavior and avoid conflicts during scheduler instance recovery?
Are there any best practices or recommended strategies for managing scheduler instances in a Quartz cluster?
Any guidance, examples, or relevant experiences shared would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!